# How do I connect FilterWebPart with ReportViewWebPart

Tags: web-part, performancepoint

I have the requirement to add performance point filter web part and report view web part to a page in SharePoint 2010 programmatically. I can add both web parts to the page however I have no idea on how to setup connection between them, i.e. for filter web part to be able to send its value to the report view web part.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to this :)

What I did was when I create the connection using SPConnectWebParts, I use TransformableBIDataProviderTransformer object, e.g.

```
   var list = new List<TransformProviderConsumerRecord>();
   var transformer = new TransformableBIDataProviderTransformer();

   var tpcRecord = new TransformProviderConsumerRecord();
   tpcRecord = "SqlReportViewUniqueParameterIdSI1";
   tpcRecord.ProviderParameterName = "FilterValues";
   tpcRecord.DisplayColumnName = "DisplayValue";
   tpcRecord.MappingId = (new Guid()).ToString();
   tpcRecord.ProviderParameterDisplayName = "PerformancePoint Values";
   tpcRecord.TypeFullName = "System.String";
   tpcRecord.ValuesColumnName = "DisplayValue";

   list.Add(transformProvConsRecord);
   ProviderConsumerTransformations provConsTransf = new    ProviderConsumerTransformations(list);

   var tcr = new TransformerConfigurationRecord(provConsTransf, new       TransformConditionalVisibilityRecord());
   transformer.ConfigurationState = tcr;

   wpm.SPConnectWebParts(providerWp, providerConnection, consumerWp, consumerConnection, transformer);
```

Where providerWP is Performance Point filter web part amd consumerWp is Performance Point Report